# Debugging Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging

I have stepped through my code, and it stops when the page is fully loaded, as it should.  However, their are a few buttons on the page, that I DO NOT see the names of in my code, so I can't discover where to add a breakpoint to, to follow the logical flow.  How can I see what is happening, 'behind the scenes' when one of those buttons is pressed?

EDIT---Would this be an applicable scenario to use tracing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a Page_Load event to the WebForm, you can put a breakpoint there.  That event / method will be called every time there is a server-side interaction with any of the controls on the page, followed by the button click (or whatever other interaction is occurring).  When on that breakpoint during a PostBack, you can look at the Form["__EventTarget"] value to determine what control is being invoked and the Form["__EventArgument"] may contain additional details on what event is being triggered.